# Curl command with a number [PowerShell]

Tags: powershell, curl

I'm following a Docker tutorial [docs.docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/)

It told me to `curl -4 http://localhost:4000` ,but I got invalid argument on my PowerShell.  When I try `curl http://localhost:4000`, I get the 200 response OK.

I'm wondering about the **"-4"** in the Curl command above. Is it a Docker thing? Or a typo? Does curl have a command like that?  Or it doesn't work on PowerShell? 
I'm confused.

[image]

**[additional note]**   In my PowerShell,  `curl --help` didn't work, so I didn't know what it was.  In my cmd, `curl --help` and `curl -4` works fine. In my Powershell curl  works, but curl -4  doesn't work.  Thanks to the answer, I know what `-4` means. It wasn't a typo or a docker thing. PowerShell doesn't seem to support `-4` option.

**[follow-up]** (Thank you Moerwald.)  In version 5.x of PowerShell, `curl -4` or `curl --help` command doesn't work, but in version 6.x of PowerShell, `curl -4`, `curl --help` command works.

Comment: -4 represents ipv4

Comment: if you are working on widows machine work with ubuntu terminal for building docker images fyi -> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-windows-terminal/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Powershell 5.x `curl` is an alias to `Invoke-WebRequest`:

```
PS X:\> Get-Command curl

CommandType     Name                                               Version       Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Alias           curl -> Invoke-WebRequest


PS X:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.1
...
```

However in PowerShell.Core it links to `curl.exe`:

```
PS C:\> Get-Command curl

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     curl.exe                                           7.55.1.0      C:\WINDOWS\system32\curl.exe


PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.2.0

PS C:\> curl --help | sls "-4"  

-4, --ipv4          Resolve names to IPv4 addresses
```

OS-Version:

```
 PS C:\> [System.Environment]::OSVersion        

 Platform ServicePack Version      VersionString
 -------- ----------- -------      -------------
 Win32NT             10.0.18362.0 Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18362.0
```

Comment: Thank you.l I checked my version with the command above. Mine is 5.x.  Is there a way to upgrade my powershell  in my powershell? :) (just curious)

Comment: Get PowerShell core from [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.2.0/PowerShell-6.2.0-win-x64.msi). Install the MSI. Start core version vis `pwsh`.

Comment: Or directly via PS: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.2.0/PowerShell-6.2.0-win-x64.msi -OutFile $env:TEMP\Powershell-6.msi; start $env:TEMP\Powershell-6.msi`

Comment: haha thanks a lot. you are so kind. I downloaded 6 version. I tried to delete the older version, but couldn't find it from removing app control (my os is in other langauge, so I do not know the correct term)

Comment: curl --help and curl -4  works with powershell 6 . thank you!

Comment: no it's not "linked" to curl.exe but an execution of curl.exe directly when PowerShell sees a command without extension that's not an alias. Just like notepad.exe is executed when you run `notepad`. [Newer Windows 10 versions have curl.exe added](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/tar-and-curl-come-to-windows/), and in PowerShell Core `curl` has been removed as an alias of Invoke-WebRequest so `curl` now runs `curl.exe`